# Shared Path in a Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, path-finding

I have a tree and 3 nodes `A`,`B`,`C`.The problem is to find the size of a path that `A` and `B` will share on their shortest paths to `C`.

There are 3 cases:

1. When `C` is an ancestor of `A` and `B`. In this case the answer is `min(depth(A), depth(B)) - depth(C)`
2. When `C` is an ancestor of `A` but not `B` or vice versus. In this case, the answer is `1`, just node `C`
3. This is a case I can't figure out when neither of `A` and `B` is a descendant of `C`.

I'll have many queries so I need an efficient way. Disregarding that we can get every LCA in `O(logN)`, every query should be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Algorithm with tree modification**

The simplest algorithm I could come up with may need a modification of the source tree depending on its initial representation.

1. We need to make `C` the root of the tree. So we need to change parent-child relationships within the tree.
2. Find the [lowest common ancestor (LCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) of `A` and `B`. LCA is the node with maximal depth that is the ancestor of both `A` and `B` (and `LCA(A, A) = A`).
3. The answer is `depth(LCA(A,B))`.

**Algorithm without tree modification**

If we cannot transform the tree then:

1. If `C` is the ancestor of both `A` and `B` then the answer is `depth(LCA(A, B)) - depth(C) + 1`. (You have a mistake in the question.)
   [image]
2. If `C` is the ancestor of `A` and not `B` then the answer is `1`. (and vice versa)
   [image]
3. If `C` is the descendant of `A` and not `B` then answer is `depth(C) - depth(A) + 1`. (and vice versa)
   [image]
4. If `C` is the descendant of both `A` and `B` then answer is `depth(C) -
   max(depth(A), depth(B)) + 1`.
   [image]
5. If `C` is not ancestor or descendant of `A` and `B` the answer would be distance between `C` and vertex `D = LCA(A, B)` that would be equal to `depth(C) + depth(D) - 2*depth(LCA(C, D)) + 1`.
   [image]

---

**Update**: now there is an `O(1)` per operation requirement appeared in the question. I think that only thing you can do to guarantee `O(1)` time complexity is to precompute all `LCA(i, j)`. This can be done, for example, with [Tarjan's off-line LCA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm).

Comment: The question doesn't provide information as on location of C wrt A and B. C can also lie as a descendant of A or (and) B. In that case, we would need LCD term rather than LCA term if I am correct?

Comment: @CodeHunter, the first clause is about making `C` the root of the tree.

Comment: Correct. The third case says "neither of A and B is descendant of C"

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

As [DAle pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411579/7518561) in the above answer, one approach can be based on the way he tells, i.e. by making the root of tree as `C` and then checking for path.

Another approach can be to find, in a similar way, **Lowest Common Descendant (LCD)** of both A and B. In short, we can find the first node where the path of both A and B would intersect *while going towards* C and then give the size of the path from that node to C. There can be few cases then:

1. LCD of A and B (going towards C) is A: return length of path from A to C
2. LCD of A and B (going towards C) is B: return length of path from B to C
3. LCD of A and B (going towards C) is C: return 0
4. LCD of A and B (going towards C) is a node D: return length of path from D to C